# hook_form_alter and fields in user_profile

Tags: hooks

I know how to use hook_form_alter, but I'm little confused how to achieve this:

In user profile there are tabs "View" and "Edit".

In edit I can alter the form using switch statement on user_profile_form and adding a fields, but they don't appear when I click on "View" tab.

Let's say I'm adding a new field into the user_profile_form:

```
    <?php

    /*
     * Implements hook_form_alter().
     */

    function my_module_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
            switch ($form_id) {
            case 'user_profile_form':


    $form['account']['skype_title'] = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<div class="user-profile-skype">Skype edit</div>'
            );

            $form['account']['skype'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('New Skype'),
            );

                  //krumo($form);   
            break;  

    }
}
```

How can I display this field into "View tab"?

Should I use another hook for this?

Comment: Why not just use the standard Field API and add fields to the user account entity?

Comment: You mean by creating a custom module with field API or adding fields from here: admin/config/people/accounts/fields?

Comment: Adding fields from `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`

Comment: First, I've tried that and added the text fields that I need. Later I wanted to display only a title without textfield, I mean only show as a title, but on Fields UI I didn't find that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaido24 mentioned, the profile view tab is not a form. You can add elements to it in [hook_user_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_view_alter/7.x).

Comment: This is an old thread and yes, your answer is right even tough I'm not using Drupal anymore.

Answer (score 0):

View tab is rendered view not a form. If you would like to show something at view tab then iguess you could use the hook_page_alter.